folder search with attributes filename contains filter is not returning results
Filtering search on fileType is returning results
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/<valid-project-id>/folders/<valid-folder-id>/search?filter[fileType]=<valid-file-type>

But
Filtering search on attributes.fileName-contains is not returning results even though there are matches
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/<valid-project-id>/folders/<valid-folder-id>/search?filter[attributes.fileName]-contains=<valid-search-value>

What have I missed?

The field name should depend on the attributes we get from GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents. There is no attribute called  fileName, so the API response returns empty results as expected. Therefore, please consider using attributes.name instead.
{
  "jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/folders/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.folder%3Asdfedf8wefl/contents?page%5Bnumber%5D=3"
    },
    "first": {
      "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/folders/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.folder%3Asdfedf8wefl/contents?page%5Bnumber%5D=0"
    },
    "prev": {
      "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/folders/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.folder%3Asdfedf8wefl/contents?page%5Bnumber%5D=2"
    },
    "next": {
      "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/folders/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.folder%3Asdfedf8wefl/contents?page%5Bnumber%5D=4"
    }
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "folders",
      "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.folder:hC6k4hndRWaeIVhIjvHu8w",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Plans",
        "displayName": "Plans",
        "createTime": "2015-11-27T11:11:23.000Z",
        "createUserId": "BW9RM76WZBGL",
        "createUserName": "John Doe",
        "lastModifiedTime": "2015-11-27T11:11:27.000Z",
        "lastModifiedTimeRollup": "2015-11-27T11:11:27.000Z",
        "lastModifiedUserId": "BW9RM76WZBGL",
        "lastModifiedUserName": "John Doe",
        "path": "/dm-test-root/f0cb4ba0-7722-0133-9814-0eeb7bad1e3b",
        "objectCount": 4,
        "hidden": false,
        "extension": {
          "type": "folders:autodesk.bim360:Folder",
          "version": "1.0",
          "schema": {
            "href": "/schema/v1/versions/folders%3Aautodesk.bim360%3AFolder-1.0"
          },
          "data": {
            "allowedTypes": [
              "folders",
              "items:autodesk.bim360:File",
              "items:autodesk.bim360:Document",
              "items:autodesk.bim360:TitleBlock"
            ],
            "visibleTypes": [
              "folders",
              "items:autodesk.bim360:Document"
            ],
            "namingStandardIds": []
          }
        }
      },
      "links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/folders/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.folder%3AhC6k4hndRWaeIVhIjvHu8w"
        }
      },
      "relationships": {
        "parent": {
          "links": {
            "related": {
              "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/folders/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.folder%3Asdfedf8wefl"
            }
          },
          "data": {
            "type": "folders",
            "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.folder:sdfedf8wefl"
          }
        },
        "refs": {
          "links": {
            "self": {
              "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/folders/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.folder%3AhC6k4hndRWaeIVhIjvHu8w/relationships/refs"
            },
            "related": {
              "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/folders/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.folder%3AhC6k4hndRWaeIVhIjvHu8w/refs"
            }
          }
        },
        "links": {
          "links": {
            "self": {
              "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/folders/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.folder%3AhC6k4hndRWaeIVhIjvHu8w/relationships/links"
            }
          }
        },
        "contents": {
          "links": {
            "related": {
              "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/folders/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.folder%3AhC6k4hndRWaeIVhIjvHu8w/contents"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "items",
      "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:hC6k4hndRWaeIVhIjvHu8w",
      "attributes": {
        "displayName": "my file",
        "createTime": "2015-11-27T11:11:23.000Z",
        "createUserId": "BW9RM76WZBGL",
        "createUserName": "John Doe",
        "lastModifiedTime": "2015-11-27T11:11:27.000Z",
        "lastModifiedUserId": "BW9RM76WZBGL",
        "lastModifiedUserName": "John Doe",
        "lastModifiedTimeRollup": "2015-11-27T11:11:27.000Z",
        "hidden": false,
        "reserved": true,
        "reservedTime": "2015-11-27T11:11:25.000Z",
        "reservedUserId": "BW9RM76WZBGL",
        "reservedUserName": "John Doe",
        "extension": {
          "type": "items:autodesk.bim360:File",
          "version": "1.0",
          "schema": {
            "href": "/schema/v1/versions/items%3Aautodesk.bim360%3AFile-1.0"
          },
          "data": {}
        }
      },
      "links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/items/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.lineage%3AhC6k4hndRWaeIVhIjvHu8w"
        }
      },
      "relationships": {
        "tip": {
          "links": {
            "related": {
              "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/items/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.lineage%3AhC6k4hndRWaeIVhIjvHu8w/tip"
            }
          },
          "data": {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.d34fdsg3g?version=2"
          }
        },
        "versions": {
          "links": {
            "related": {
              "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/items/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.lineage%3AhC6k4hndRWaeIVhIjvHu8w/versions"
            }
          }
        },
        "refs": {
          "links": {
            "self": {
              "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/items/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.lineage%3AhC6k4hndRWaeIVhIjvHu8w/relationships/refs"
            },
            "related": {
              "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/items/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.lineage%3AhC6k4hndRWaeIVhIjvHu8w/refs"
            }
          }
        },
        "links": {
          "links": {
            "self": {
              "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/items/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.lineage%3AhC6k4hndRWaeIVhIjvHu8w/relationships/links"
            }
          }
        },
        "parent": {
          "links": {
            "related": {
              "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/folders/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.folder%3Asdfedf8wefl"
            }
          },
          "data": {
            "type": "folders",
            "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.folder:sdfedf8wefl"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "versions",
      "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.d34fdsg3g?version=2",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "version-test.pdf",
        "displayName": "version-test.pdf",
        "createTime": "2016-04-01T11:09:03.000Z",
        "createUserId": "BW9RM76WZBGL",
        "createUserName": "John Doe",
        "lastModifiedTime": "2016-04-01T11:11:18.000Z",
        "lastModifiedUserId": "BW9RM76WZBGL",
        "lastModifiedUserName": "John Doe",
        "versionNumber": 2,
        "mimeType": "application/pdf",
        "extension": {
          "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:File",
          "version": "1.0",
          "schema": {
            "href": "/schema/v1/versions/versions%3Aautodesk.bim360%3AFile-1.0"
          },
          "data": {
            "tempUrn": null,
            "properties": {},
            "storageUrn": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/3c8f6bbc-fe5c-4815-a92e-8b8635e7b1cb.pdf",
            "storageType": "OSS",
            "conformingStatus": "NONE"
          }
        }
      },
      "links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/versions/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Afs.file%3Avf.b909RzMKR4mhc3O7UBY_8g%3Fversion%3D1"
        },
        "webView": {
          "href": "https://docs.b360.autodesk.com/projects/c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/folders/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Afs.folder%3Aco.0J4paz_FQgWPX2QRsaBkiw/detail/viewer/items/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Afs.file%3Avf.b909RzMKR4mhc3O7UBY_8g%3Fversion%3D1"
        }
      },
      "relationships": {
        "item": {
          "links": {
            "related": {
              "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/items/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.lineage%3Ab909RzMKR4mhc3O7UBY_8g"
            }
          },
          "data": {
            "type": "items",
            "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:b909RzMKR4mhc3O7UBY_8g"
          }
        },
        "refs": {
          "links": {
            "self": {
              "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/versions/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Afs.file%3Avf.b909RzMKR4mhc3O7UBY_8g%3Fversion%3D1/relationships/refs"
            },
            "related": {
              "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/versions/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Afs.file%3Avf.b909RzMKR4mhc3O7UBY_8g%3Fversion%3D1/refs"
            }
          }
        },
        "links": {
          "links": {
            "self": {
              "href": "/data/v1/projects/b.c2960674-2d1e-4cc8-a5f0-4b9026fd3f5d/versions/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Afs.file%3Avf.b909RzMKR4mhc3O7UBY_8g%3Fversion%3D1/relationships/links"
            }
          }
        },
        "storage": {
          "meta": {
            "link": {
              "href": "/oss/v2/buckets/wipbucket/objects/3c8f6bbc-fe5c-4815-a92e-8b8635e7b1cb.pdf?scopes=b360project.6f8813fe-31a7-4440-bc63-d8ca97c856b4,global,O2tenant.tenantId"
            }
          },
          "data": {
            "type": "objects",
            "id": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/3c8f6bbc-fe5c-4815-a92e-8b8635e7b1cb.pdf"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

